# Remove reCAPTCHA Dialog

Tags: java, android, recaptcha

I am using reCAPTCHA Android Library in my app. **Is it possible to remove the Dialog box in when it is retrieving the results.** *(Below is the sample of dialog box)*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must have chosen the last option. For hidden reCaptcha, you need to choose middle option - Invisible reCAPTCHA badge.

[image]

Source - https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions